# Question about trigonometry inequality

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Please how to find $y\in [0,\pi]$ which satisfy $\cos(y)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-T)$ where $T\in [-\pi,\pi]$?

If $\frac{\pi}{2}-T\in [0,\pi]$ then $y=\frac{\pi}{2}-T$

but what about the other cases ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two general solutions

$$y_1=\frac{\pi}{2}-T+2k\pi$$
and

$$y_2=-(\frac{\pi}{2}-T) +2k\pi$$

assuming  that $$-a \le T \le a$$

we get

$$ -a-\frac{\pi}{2} +2k\pi \le y_1\le a-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$
and

$$-a+\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \le y_2\le a+\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$

Choose now $k$ and $a$ to satisfy the condition on $y$.

Comment: why a ? @hamam_Abdallah please

Comment: @lindaOiladali If $a=\pi$ you are not sur that the solution is in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: in the first equation a found $a=\pi/2$ and $k=1/2$ but it is not possible

Comment: @lindaOiladali $k$ is integer.

Comment: @lindaOiladali This answer gives a more general solution than you asked for. For your particular question, you asked for $-\pi\leq T\leq\pi$ so you can set $a=\pi.$

Comment: @DavidK if  I replace $a$ by $\pi$ and suppose $\pi-\pi/2+2k\pi\leq\pi$ and  $-\pi-\pi/2+2k\pi\geq0$ i get a contradiction, please help me to find a solution

Comment: @lindaOiladali You have the $-$ signs in the wrong places. It should be $-\pi-\frac\pi2+2k\pi \leq \pi$ and $\pi-\frac\pi2+2k\pi \geq 0.$

Comment: @DavidK the first gives me k=0 and the second a contradiction

Comment: $k=0$ works for the second inequality too. I will admit, though, I haven’t yet seen how these inequalities lead to the required result.